# TypeError: In a simple loop of code

Tags: python-2.7

I've tried to solve my problem by googling, but every time someone has the same problem also has complicated code. I a noob and I have no idea why It keeps having an error called "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" Even though I tried converting some of the variables to int. (I'm probably solving it the wrong way). Can someone give a heads up without giving me the answer?

```
x = range(2, 20)
number = 0
y = raw_input()
flag = True

while flag == True:
    for elem in x:
        if y % elem == 0:
            print elem
        else:
            flag = False
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is convert the raw_input()  into integer using int() function. That's will solve the program. You can do this by:

```
       y = int(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, when you read an input with raw_input(), you receive a string, and you are treating the variable `y` later on your code as an integer (at `if y % elem == 0:`). You need to cast the input to an integer, which can be done substituting this line

```
y = raw_input()
```

for this line:

```
y = int(raw_input())
```